# React: Modal containing form won't recognise a a prop of type function being passed down to it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

This is a very specific issue I have searched this site and the web for hours trying to resolve it.  Mod please don't disable this post with out reading completely.
I can pass function to control the state easily.
I can pass objects arrays to modal easily

This issue is specifically passing a function to a modal which contains a registration form - upon completion of the form I want to change the state.

```
class Users extends Component {

  aPropVal = 'works fine';

  // passing the following function as prop to any other (non-modal) component works fine
  addUserStart = (data) => {
    console.log('addUserStart has been fired')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="main">
          <ModalAddUser  addUserStart={this.addUserStart} aprop={this.aPropVal} />
...
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

export default Users

then the ModalAddUserObject which works perfectly in every way - exception being the function won't pass

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button,  FormGroup, Input, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter } from 'reactstrap';

    const ModalAddUser = (props) => {

        console.log('props for ModalAddUser: ' + JSON.stringify(props))
    ...
    }
```

console.log =

> props for ModalAddUser: {"aprop":"works fine"}

Comment: please post a link to codesandbox.io if possible

Comment: Here is a link to code sandbox and it seems to work fine .. https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-heisenberg-ubpjg

Comment: thank you - I have to assume some other element (included libraries or scripting error which does not show at run time) is the limiting factor.  Please let me take the time to post more of the code on sandbox.

Comment: i have posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON.stringify wouldn't serialize functions. if you try console.log(props) you should see your functions.

[image]

Comment: You are correct I am sorry for this oversight.  It was not firing due to some other reason but in fact it was being passed.  Thank you for providing another set of eyes - this was something very simple but I did not see it.

Comment: No worries Happy to help. The simplest of bugs are sometimes harder to catch :)